# Modal re-render issues with TextInput - Modal keeps reanimating

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My modal constantly refreshes (closes and reopens through animation, while additionally closing the keyboard) as the state change when someone writes into the `TextInput`. This is an extremely frustrating issue that I can't seem to fix. Please help.

Text Input code, which is within the Modal:

```
<TextInput 
  keyboardType="numeric"
  value = {this.state.input_weight}
  onChangeText = {(val) =>  {this.setState({input_weight: val})}}
  autoFocus = {true}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  placeholderTextColor="orange" 
  style = {{color:'white', textAlign: 'center', 
  justifyContent:'center', width:'100%', height:'100%'}}
  placeholder = {this.dictionary.submit_weight[this.state.language]}
  maxLength={5}>
</TextInput>
```

Modal options and code:

```
<Modal
  isVisible = {this.state.weight_modal}
  animationType="slide" 
  onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({weight_modal: false})}>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Do you set weight_modal on somewhere except Modal component? You should share all code

Comment: The entire code is almost 600 lines, so I was wary of posting all of it for that reason. After setting input_weight and weight_modal in the state, I have a TouchableOpacity that when clicked upon triggers this code:  () => {this.setState({weight_modal: false})}. Nothing else triggers it.

Comment: The entire thing is in a single component, so input_weight and weight_modal are in the same state. When I setState for input_weight the modal is re-rendered causing the animation to happen again, which is extremely jerky. I'm 100% sure this is the issue, I just don't know how to fix it.